# How to test the cross-compiled tensorflow lite?

Tags: cross-compiling, tensorflow-lite, riscv

I want to deploy dnn models on nezha Linux SBC with Xuantie C906 core.
I cross-compile the tensorflow lite successfully.
`export RISCVCC_PREFIX=/home/fcqiao/Xuantie-900-gcc-linux-5.10.4-glibc-x86_64-V2.6.1/bin/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-`
`export RISCVCC_FLAGS="-march=rv64gcv0p7_zfh_xtheadc -mabi=lp64d"`
`cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${RISCVCC_PREFIX}gcc   -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${RISCVCC_PREFIX}g++   -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="${RISCVCC_FLAGS}"   -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="${RSICVCC_FLAGS}"   -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON   -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux   -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=c906 -DTFLITE_ENABLE_XNNPACK=OFF ../tensorflow/lite/`
And I can find a ".a" file which is the "libtensorflow.a".
And then, I can use it successfully.
When I compile the ".cpp" with the following command, `/home/fcqiao/Xuantie-900-gcc-linux-5.10.4-glibc-x86_64-V2.6.1/bin/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++ -o out test.cpp -march=rv64gcv0p7_zfh_xtheadc -mabi=lp64d -I ../../tensorflow/lite/ ../libtensorflow-lite.a -lm -static`
It always pops errors that tensorflow/lite/model.h: No such file or directory.

1.I really want to figure out how to use this tflite.
2.It is better to further how to use customized ops in this tflite.

Comment: I tried to use this static library. It turns out there is an error about 
 the function, `pthread_mutex_unlock`, which is associated with `tflite::ops::BuiltinOpResolver`. However, I notice that `inline void pthread_mutex_unlock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex) { (*mutex)->unlock(); }`, which is in `build/gemmlowp/profiling/pthread_everywhere.h`. I don't know how to fix this!

Comment: I scan the error messages and I found that it seems that the compiler that I use doesn't have necessary definition on `pthread_mutex_unlock`. Because C906 is a single 64-bit RISCV core, it doesn't involve the use of "pthread". Maybe I will try another cores.

Comment: What errors messages do you get ? Also I think not having toolchain support for pthreads has nothing to do with running on a single core processor. You can build the [GNU toolchain for RISC-V](https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain) with `-mtune=c906`

Comment: The compiler that I used is from Xuantie binary cross-compiler, which supports `-pthread`, therefore the errors on `pthread_mutex_unlock` seems ok. I compiled the libtensorflow-lite.a with no errors. However, when I use this library in code, it shows errors like "undefined rdft()" and some functions in ruy. I use command `nm libtensorflow-lite.a | grep rdft`, it shows `U` signals which means undefined functions. Also, I tried to comile tensorflow-lite without "ruy" library, however, I seems impossible because a lot of functions in `lite/kernels` involves "ruy". So difficult!